# Template function with static variable

Tags: c++

I have 2 functions with almost same impelementation so in order to optimise the code, We propose to create a template function.

Bellow just an example of the template function:

```
template<typename typo>
int func_test1(typo input)
{
   static int var;
   if (A)
   {
      var = input;
   }
   else if(B)
   {
      var = 1;
   }
   else
   {
      // do nothing
   }
   return var;
}
```

In case I called the template function created the first time and the condition A for example was true so the return value should be equal to input.
If I call it the second time, and in case conditions A and B are not true, and since var is static is that mean it will keep the previous value?

I hope that my question is clear?

Comment: I add the template parameter

Comment: The answer depends on which specialization of the template you are calling. There will be one `static` variable for each specialization, i.e. type `typo`.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: please show the code instead of describing it. Post a [mcve].

Comment: Note that what you show isn't really a "template function" (whatever that is) but a function template. Functions will be created from that template for each different type used in the call, and each of those will be *different* functions, with *different* `var`.

Answer (score 2):

`func_test1` is a function template (not a template function, it is not a function). `func_test1<Foo>` and `func_test1<Bar>` are two distinct functions each with their own static variable, unless `Foo` is the same type as `Bar`.